# SSRS Multiple Parameters in a single dropdown

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report I need to develop where all Quotes should be listed where a specific Product is present. The product can be identified based on Product ID/Price/Product Name etc. I was looking to develop one report where all there fields are present as part of a dropdown. When the user selects one value such as Product ID and enters a value in the text box next to the ID, the report is filtered on this parameter. If the user selects name, the name can be entered in the text box and the report is filtered based on the Vendor ID etc.

Is there a way to do this? I have the parameters showing up next to each other instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable if I understand correctly and here are the steps for achieving your report purpose. 
I will use a simple query as an example data set for your reference.

1.Create source and `datasets`, in this example I skip the `data sources` and here is the short query for my exmaple

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE 
(ID = @ID or @ID = '')
 and 
(Name = @Name or @Name = '')
```

2.Add another `dataset` named `Control`, the query for `Control` is:

```
SELECT 'ID' as option
UNION
SELECT 'Name' as option
```

The purpose of creating this `dataset` is to provide the available values later when you need to choose either name or ID.

3.After step1, you should already have two parameters generated by system, which are `ID` and `Name`, if not, create them by yourself and go to each parameter page, **DO MAKE SURE CHECK `Allow blank value''`**

4.Create the 3rd parameter called `Control`, go to parameter setting page, go to `Available Values`, Choose `Control` dataset, Choose `option` (which is the customize column name you set in `Control`dataset) for both `Value field` and `Label field`

5.Go to `ID` parameter setting page, go to `Default Values`, choose `Specify values`, click `fx`, type this:

```
=Switch(Parameters!Control.Value="Name","")
```

Click ok

6.Go to `Name` parameter setting page, go to `Default Values`, choose `Specify values`, click `fx`, type this:

```
=Switch(Parameters!Control.Value="ID","")
```

Click ok

**The `ID` and `Name` expression are correct, not set wrong**

7.Change the parameter order to make `Control` on the VERY TOP, no matter `ID` or `Name` comes for the 2nd, but `Control` should be in the 1st place.

8.Drag and drop a table, place `Name` and `ID`. Preview the report, at this time, only `Control` will be available for you to choose value, choose either ID or Name to see the difference. When you choose `ID`, `Name` will be gray out, only `ID` light up and type any ID you want, actually, what the system does internally is passing the `""` (blank value) to `Name`, that is why you need to make sure the `Name` parameter could accept blank value. Same for selecting `Name`

Update me if you have any run time issue